# What is the history of the wave and heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-history, heat-equation, wave-equation

I have a project in which we need talk to about the history of the wave and heat equation. I can’t seem to find much information about it( ie when it was discovered/derived, who discovered it, and any advancements). If you know anywhere online or any textbooks that might have such information, please let me know!

Comment: With reference given: [Jean-Baptiste le Rond d'Alembert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) discovered the wave equation in one space dimension. For the heat equation please try now the other usual suspect.

Comment: This kind of post really belongs on the stackexchange site [history of science and math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). Even there you should probably search first. A quick search, for example, yielded [this hit](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12308/history-behind-the-heat-equation).